# AMP Resizable Iframe on Safari does not shrink

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, amp-html

The recommended Code to send the current height of the Iframe document to the parent AMP Iframe is:

```
window.parent.postMessage({
  sentinel: 'amp',
  type: 'embed-size',
  height: document.body.scrollHeight
}, '*');
```

(from https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe#iframe-resizing)

This seems to cause problems on Safari when trying to "shrink" the Iframe.

**It seems that on Safari `document.body.scrollHeight` returns the Iframe height if the Iframe is bigger than the content.**

So in that case the postMessage sends the current height of the Iframe and the Iframe height never gets changed by the Amp-Code.

I tried `document.contentWindow.scrollHeight`in Safari and that seems to work as expected.

Is it a known bug?

Comment: There is an existing bug that was  file last 2017: [Responsive iframes on iOS do not size correctly (workaround included)](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11133), you can try the provided workaround it does solve your issue. If not, try commenting on that reported bug.